# Is there a way to verify if the Catch part of a try/catch instruction is called in a test method when using JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

For example, if I had the following class that I want to test:

```
public class SomeClass{
    public void someMethod() {
        try {
            //Some code, where comething could go wrong
        } catch (Exception err) {
            //Handling it amounts to logging the problem and trying to continue
        }
    }
 }
```

If I then test this method with JUnit, then if something does go wrong in the try clause and the catch code is run, then the test will pass.

I want to make it so that the test will fail if the catch clause instructions are run.

I did think of a few ways I could try and write tests so that I get an equivalent sort of functionality, but there are reasons for each one that I do not want to approach it that way. It seems like trying to fail the test if any catch clause is reached is the cleanest way to do this, if that is in fact possible

**Notes:**

I know I could verify certain features of the code and check if they are a certain value/have been run a number of times with Mockito. However I want a solution where if changes were made to the test method that radically altered how it worked (but not what task was essentially being carried out) then I won't have to rewrite the test.

Unfortunately, just to make this proble more difficult, I am unable to make any modifictions to the source code. This position is out of my control so I have to work within these confines.

---

**EDIT:**

SomeClass is the class that I wish to test. It is not the actual JUnit test. I have edited my original question to try and clarify this.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you can't use Mockito's behaviour driven features to just fail in case any line of code inside the catch clause is ran. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Grasshopper The code posted is the class under test, so it can (and should) not depend on a test framework.

Comment: Yes @Thirler, I'm sorry for any ambiguity. The example above is the method that I want to test, not the actual test itself.

Comment: @Seb I got that, but in the post you mention mockito's BD features. Why not just assert that any of the methods invoked in the catch clause are not invoked? And aren't you already using JUnit and Mockito? What do you mean by 'not depend on a test framework'?

Comment: In some situations methods called in the catch clause may also be called outside of the catch clause, but with different parameters given. At the moment the only one that isn't is the logger. In case this changes in future I would like to avoid that too. I would like to find some way of testing methods like this in a consistant way, and the most generic way I have thought of was to try and verify if the catch clause is executed.

Comment: If you want to fail the unit test, in the most general sense, when ever a catch clause is executed by the code in this method you are going to have to instrument the byte code to tell you when a catch clause is being executed. This is a complex task. I would not recommend this.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping this was something that had been implemented but I had managed to miss in the documentation I'd read / Was easy to implement myself. I think I will just have to use a less generic pattern to test these methods and tailor each test to the method it tests.

Comment: Why do you want your test to fail when the method under test is not failing? It sounds like you're trying to get rid of a checked exception, but still worried about it happening. You should rethink how the caught exception is handled, maybe wrapping it in a RuntimeException or, if appropriate, puting it in the method's throws clause.

Comment: @BrettWalker: I'd be interessted on how you would do that. Can you help (http://stackoverflow.com/q/30621542/12860) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had to deal with this sort of problem before. I ended up mocking the logging sub-system (not simple but not overly complex) and listened for the 'interesting' logging calls, and then flagging failures when it happened.

Comment: So you suggest mocking the logger and then asserting if it's called? At the moment that would work, because logger is only called by when an exception is thrown. 

Ideally I would like to make it cleaner, in case in the future we require this method (Or similar methods) to also log something in a case where no exception has been thrown. If there are no more generic ways though then this is good, thank you.

Comment: You can package the Mock Logging sub-system as a tool/library to be used in you testing framework, again and again and again. Make what you want to be (or not want to be) logged configurable.

Comment: There are other more advanced options, but this is the way that I would recommend.  Intercept the logging calls.   (for reference, the more advanced approaches are 1) instrument/rewrite the byte code as it is loaded for SomeClass and 2) put the JVM into debug mode and subscribe to all exception throws.. neither approach is straight forward though).

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you are testing the behavior of this function. Your test should not care (so not test) that an exception is caught, just that the behavior you want happens.

This means that if you want to test that something is (or isn't) logged. Then you have to verify somethings is logged. In several of my applications I have made a distinction between debug logging and important logmessage. The latter we send through a class (in our case we used the Facade design pattern). that we can mock (and thus test the calls). For most applications, much of the developer logging does not have to be tested, so in those cases you should ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any framework which let you assert exceptions were thown and handled in the method and not propagated. From the problem description I'd see two approaches, both using BDD:

1. Assert a line of code inside the catch block is not invoked - the logger would be a good option as @Thirler suggests
2. Assert the Exception constructor is not invoked

Both have problems:

1. Not very clean as you desire because it is tightly coupled to the actual code being executed.
2. Any exception handled in the code will trigger a failure.

You could try using aspectj to instrument the code and flag that an exception has been thrown while executing ***SomeClass.someMethod***.

Answer (score 0):

In a general way,

-1- Checking that some function f() throws an exception

```
try {
  f();
  // notify test failure here
} catch (...) {
  // success
};
```

-2- Checking that it doesnt

```
try {
   f();
} catch(...) {
   // notify test failure here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you may consider using [assert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html)

what is assert you may ask:

> An assertion is a statement in the JavaTM programming language that enables you to test your assumptions about your program. For example, if you write a method that calculates the speed of a particle, you might assert that the calculated speed is less than the speed of light.

I'm not going through the details as I couldn't explain it better than its own documentations.

Comment: How would that help? Where would you put the assert? SomeClass cannot be modified.