# How to instrument the byte code to tell when a catch clause is being executed?

Tags: java, exception, bytecode

Based on [Brett Walker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870743/brett-walker)'s comment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30620397/12860), I was wondering how it can be done.

"If you want to fail the unit test, in the most general sense, when ever a catch clause is executed by the code in this method you are going to have to instrument the byte code to tell you when a catch clause is being executed. This is a complex task. I would not recommend this."

How would I test that some method has executed a catch clause? (the `isCatched()` in the example below.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class A {
  public void method() {
    try {
      // some code that may or may not throw an exception
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // do nothing
    }
  }
}
```

And then somewhere else:

```
public class CatchTester {
  private A a;
  public CatchTester(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  public boolean isCatched() {
    // how to do this?
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never done any byte code instrumenting. I believe it is a powerful but subtle/complex tool. My comment was more a hunch (based upon experience/expectations) rather than a statement of fact. But I too would be interested to know if this is possible...

Comment: I don’t understand how `CatchTester` shall be involved in `A`.

Comment: isCatched() calls `a.method();` and returns true if an Exception is catched and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches, both require knowledge of how to manipulate Java Byte codes. Tools such as [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) exist for making manipulating byte codes a little easier.  One would then wire in a [Java Agent](http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents/) or write a custom class loader that modified the class bytes as they were loaded into the JVM.

A very good example of this approach, is https://github.com/google/allocation-instrumenter.  Allocation-Instrumenter modifies the byte codes of a class so that one can register a callback method that is called when ever a object allocation occurs.  It is not much of a stretch to imagine a similar library for try/catch instrumentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect via Instrumentation whether a certain code has been executed, you have to modify the code, injecting some sort of logging code which will effectively call back a method recording the fact that this code has been hit. Then you can check whether such a record exists right after the examined method returns.

While it wouldn’t be hard to insert such a logging code right at the beginning of each exception handler, there is the problem that on the byte code level, no distinction between `catch`, `finally` or `try(…)` clauses is made. They all end up with defining exception handlers, some of them might re-throw catched exceptions. If you want to exclude handlers which re-throw exceptions, you would have to trace every possible code path, beginning at the exception handler’s entry, checking whether it ends in a normal completion or throws an exception, either the catched or another newly constructed one.

If you just want to know whether *any* `catch` clause has been executed, the case is much simpler. If an exception has been thrown during `method()`’s execution but `method()` completes normally, i.e. the caller does not receive the exception, there *must* have been an exception handler executed.